# Get id from tree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tree structure:

```css
<style>
.Container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Container li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* indent for all tree children excepts root */
.Node {
    margin-left: 18px;
    zoom: 1;

}

.IsRoot {
    margin-left: 0;
}
 
.ExpandOpen .Expand {
    background-image:      url(/tree_accordion/treeacc/pictures/minus.gif);
}
 
/* closed is higher priority than open */
.ExpandClosed .Expand {
    background-image: url(/tree_accordion/treeacc/pictures/plus.gif);
}
 
/* highest priority */
.ExpandLeaf .Expand {
    /* background-image: url(/tree_accordion/treeacc/pictures/leaf.gif); */
    background-image: none;
}

.Content {
    min-height: 18px;
    margin-left:18px;
}
* html  .Content {
    height: 18px;
}


.ExpandLoading   {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(/tree_accordion/treeacc/pictures/loading.gif);
}

.Expand {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    float: left;
}


.ExpandOpen .Container {
    display: block;
}

.ExpandClosed .Container {
    display: none;
}

.ExpandOpen .Expand, .ExpandClosed .Expand {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ExpandLeaf .Expand {
    cursor: auto;
}

.Node input {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    float: left; 
    margin: 2px;
}
</style>
```

js

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function tree_toggle(event) {
    event = event || window.event
    var clickedElem = event.target || event.srcElement

    if (!hasClass(clickedElem, 'Expand')) {
        return;
    }

    // Node, onClick
    var node = clickedElem.parentNode
    if (hasClass(node, 'ExpandLeaf')) {
        return;
    }

    // new class for node
    var newClass = hasClass(node, 'ExpandOpen') ? 'ExpandClosed' : 'ExpandOpen'
    var re =  /(^|\s)(ExpandOpen|ExpandClosed)(\s|$)/
    node.className = node.className.replace(re, '$1'+newClass+'$3')
}


function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+className+"(\\s|$)").test(elem.className)
}

</script>
```

html

```html
<div onclick="tree_toggle(arguments[0])">
  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
  <div class="Expand"> </div>
  <div class="Content">XXX</div>
       
                 <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                   <div class="Expand"> </div>
                   <div class="Content">aaa</div>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.1.1">a1</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.1.2">a2</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.1.3">a3</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                 </li></ul>
                 
                 <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                   <div class="Expand"> </div>
                   <div class="Content">bbb</div>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.2.1">b1</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.2.2">b2</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                 </li></ul>
                                  
                 <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                   <div class="Expand"> </div>
                   <div class="Content">ccc</div>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.3.1">c1</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                 </li></ul>
                                  
  </li></ul>

  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
  <div class="Expand"> </div>
  <div class="Content">YYY</div>
                 <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandClosed">
                   <div class="Expand"> </div>
                   <div class="Content">ddd</div>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="2.1.1">d1</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                                  <ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
                                    <div class="Expand"> </div>
                                    <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="2.1.2">d2</label></div>
                                  </li></ul>
                 </li></ul>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the clicked list element. Without onClick to each element and JQuery.
So, I know as with simple structure:

```
<ul id="sss">
<li id="1.1.1"></li>
<li id="1.1.2"></li>
</ul>
```

Works:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('sss');

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if (e.target.tagName === 'LI'){
  alert(e.target.id);
}
```

});

I wish to receive at a click on checkbox (or label) my id. For example: 1.1.1 or 1.1.2 ... 
At construction of a tree I can modify my block from:

```html
<ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast">
  <div class="Expand"> </div>
  <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox" id="1.1.1">a1</label></div>
</li></ul>
```

to

```html
<ul class="Container"><li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast" id="1.1.1">
  <div class="Expand"> </div>
  <div class="Content"><label><input type="checkbox">a1</label></div>
</li></ul>
```

But can not create correctly function. Help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of event delegation it's important to find a correct node, since event bubbles up the DOM tree. Usually `while` loop is used for this. You start from `e.target` element, and then check if it meets you condition (CSS selector, tag name, etc.). You repeat it until you find out that event occurred within interested container (success - handle event), or until you get to the host element (used to register event on; do nothing in this case). Then the search is finished.

In your case it will be something like this:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('sss');

ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    while (target !== ul) {
        if (target.tagName === 'LI') {
            alert(target.id);
            return;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
});
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('sss');

ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    
    var target = e.target;
    
    // Label generates one more click event on the related input element, suppress one
    if (target.tagName === 'LABEL') {
        return;
    }
    
    while (target !== ul) {
        if (target.tagName === 'LI') {
            alert(target.id);
            return;
        }
        target = target.parentNode
    }
});
```

```html
<ul class="Container" id="sss">
    <li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast" id="1.1.1">
        <div class="Expand">expand</div>
        <div class="Content">
            <label><input type="checkbox" />a1</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="Node ExpandLeaf IsLast" id="1.1.2">
        <div class="Expand">expand</div>
        <div class="Content">
            <label><input type="checkbox" />a2</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do not work.
I do not know where in my structure should be id = "SSS"
That worked for all leaf.

Comment: Use `Container` class instead of id then.

Comment: Your example works. Thanks. 
I can not fasten to my case for all leafs from groups XXX, YYY ...
Through a class ' SSS' too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. document.getElementsByClassName("SSS")[0] works for me.

Comment: Maybe document.querySelector(".SSS") will be more convenient.

Comment: Your help very much price.
If I have correctly understood, it works faster, and on a step above for IE.
For IE7 -- only onClick? It is possible to do for ~2000 leafs? Thanks.